# Can't find variable: styled StyledComponents React Native

Tags: react-native, styled-components

Seguindo [este tutorial](https://blog.rocketseat.com.br/react-native-autenticacao/)

Foi instalado através do yarn o styled-components:

```
yarn add axios prop-types react-navigation styled-components
```

Então no meu arquivo styles.js eu defini uma classe:

```
const Container = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    alignItems: center;
    justifyContent: center;
    backgroundColor: #00a999;
`;
```

E no final exporto:

```
export { Container, Logo, Input, ErrorMessage, Button, ButtonText, SignUpLink, SignUpLinkText };
```

Porém eu recebo:

> Can't find variable: styled

No tutorial cita alguma coisa sobre isso:

> Como você deve ter percebido não usamos mais o
>   StyleSheet.create()passando um objeto como parâmetro, com o Styled
>   Components criamos uma constante para cada componente com o prefixo
>   styled., em seguida dentro de um bloco de crases
>   (`) passamos os estilos igual CSS, sem o uso de apóstrofe (‘) nem
>   vírgula(,) no final das linhas, portanto seguindo esse padrão de
>   nomeação você pode criar qualquer componente como se estivesse usando
>   o StyleSheet.

Comment: Voce poderia adicionar todo o conteudo do arquivo styles.js na pergunta? Facilitaria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pela mensagem de erro, parece que faltou importar o styled components para o seu arquivo de estilos. Aqui tem um exemplo de:

```js
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const Container = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    alignItems: center;
    justifyContent: center;
    backgroundColor: #00a999;
`;

export const ImageBackground = styled.ImageBackground`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;

export const Logo = styled.Image`
  width: 72px;
  height: 72px;
`;
```

No arquivo onde eu vou utilizar estes estilos,eu importo da seguinte forma:

```
import {ImageBackground,Container,Logo} from "./styles";
```